# Showing that $E[X^2] = E[Y^2]$ for two RV following Frechet distributions with different location parameters only

Tags: moments, exponential-family

If random variable X follows a Fréchet distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) with shape parameter $\alpha$, scale parameter $s$, and location parameter $m$, that is

$X \sim F(\alpha,s,m)$

Now if we have another random variable $Y \sim F(\alpha,s,m')$ (the only difference being the location parameter $m' \neq m$), could we say that their second-order moments are equal, i.e.

$E[X^2] = E[Y^2]$ ?

Intuitively, I would say *yes*, but is it possible to demonstrate it?

Comment: I would say no because the variance of Frechet distribution does not depend on the location parameter, but the mean does. And since the second moment can be written as variance plus mean squared, it also depends on $m$.

Comment: I see, it makes sense! thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the answer is no they will not be equal to each other. The comment by @misius is an excellent way to show this, but it does assume that the mean and variance are finite and defined. Technically, we can have equality in the sense that $E(X^2) = E(Y^2) = \infty$ whenever $\alpha < 2$. Still, the spirit of the answer is correct.

---

Here's an additional proof that demonstrates the fact directly.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $X \sim F(a, s, 0)$ and $Y \sim F(a, s, m)$, with $m > 0$. It is obvious that $Y = X+m$ in distribution.

\begin{align*}
E(Y^2) &= E\left((X+m)^2\right) \\
&= E\left(X^2 + 2mX + m^2\right) \\
&= E(X^2) + 2m E(X) + m^2.
\end{align*}

For $E(Y^2) = E(X^2)$ to hold, we need $2mE(X) + m^2 = 0$. But both of these quantities must be positive since we have assumed that $m > 0$ and since $X$ has positive support. Therefore the equality can only hold in the non-interesting case where $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$ are both infinity.